How to deploy a Firebase Function using Google Cloud Build?
I'm trying to deploy a Firebase Cloud Function using Google Cloud Build.
Snippet of the cloudbuild.yaml that fails:
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/firebase"
  entrypoint: bash
  args:
    - -c
    - |
      firebase deploy --only functions:createUserRecord --project $PROJECT_ID

When I run the Cloud Build process, I encounter the following error:
Step #3: Error response from daemon: manifest for gcr.io/cloud-builders/firebase:latest not found: manifest unknown: Failed to fetch "latest"

When deploying the function directly through the Firebase CLI, it is deployed fine. However, via a Cloud Build trigger it is failing to build.

just to check - are you sure that the "gcr.io/cloud-builders/firebase" is correct?

It turns out I needed to first install Java. Here is the final snippet that worked:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm
  entrypoint: bash
  dir: edcloud/cloud-function/${_PROJECT_NAME}
  args:
    - -c
    - |
      apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk
      npm install -g firebase-tools
      npm install
      firebase emulators:exec --project $PROJECT_ID 'npm test'

